# JSF element loaded with relative url in external context

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jsf

I have a content script that shows a floating div on the top of the web browser pages. The div is filled with some content of my web application (says at www.my.app/my/page) through jQuery.load or jQuery.get.

While the HTML contents of the page are ok, resources like images are not loaded. Generated HTML for the image looks like

```
<img src=/my/image/path>
```

If the content script is applied to the site www.asite.com, the browser will try to get the image from www.asite.com/my/image/path instead of www.my.app/my/image/path.

The image in question is generated from jsf using

```
 <p:graphicImage value="#{tagImageController.imageFileContent}"/>
```

and works fine in the correct context (on the correct domain). If my content scripts use an iframe instead of a div, it works fine.

Here is the imageFileContent function:

```
public StreamedContent getImageFileContent() {
    FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    ExternalContext externalContext = facesContext.getExternalContext();
    Map<String, String> requestParameterMap = externalContext.getRequestParameterMap();
    String tagIdStr = requestParameterMap.get("tag_id");
    if (tagIdStr == null || tagIdStr.isEmpty()) {
        streamedContent = defaultStreamedContent;
    } else {
        long tagId = Long.parseLong(tagIdStr);
        Tag tag = tagService.findTag(tagId);
        if (tag == null) {
            streamedContent = defaultStreamedContent;
        }
        streamedContent = loadImageStreamedContent(tag);
    }
    return streamedContent;
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't control the domain of `<p:graphicImage>` with streamed content.

Just use plain HTML `<img>` with a `@WebServlet` serving the dynamic image content. Then you can fully control the `<img>`'s domain.

E.g.

```
<img src="//www.my.app/my/image/path" />
```

with something like this

```
@WebServlet("/image/*")
public class ImageServlet extends HttpServlet {

    @EJB
    private SomeImageService someImageService;

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        String path = request.getPathInfo().substring(1);
        Image image = someImageService.findSomehowBy(path);
        String filename = image.getFilename();
        byte[] content = image.getContent();

        response.setHeader("Content-Type", getServletContext().getMimetype(filename));
        response.setHeader("Content-Length", String.valueOf(content.length));
        response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=\"" + filename + "\"");
        response.getOutputStream().write(content);
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks. I was attempting to filter somehow, but this works great!